# What project type to use in Netbeans for Javascript/HTML/CSS application?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

According to the Netbeans site (http://netbeans.org/features/javascript/index.html), Netbeans can be used for "Developing with HTML, JavaScript, and CSS". However, the IDE does not ship with a project type just for this. Instead, there is a project type for PHP or (if you have a release before 7.0), Ruby etc.
However, I just want to create a rich web application with Javascript/HTML/CSS. Perhaps there is a plugin for such a project type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no plugin to create HTML project or General project (as in Eclipse).
But for this I use **Favorites** tab:

1. Display tab Favorites Windows >
   Favorites
2. Find your directory for your html
   project
3. Right click to directory and choose
   "Add To Favorites"

[image]

Comment: I hate to admit it, but it seems like this is the only decent answer. I am really disappointed that there is not some generic web editing project type for Netbeans, and I guess Oracle, having taken over, will never consider putting some effort behind such an endeavour.

Answer (score 5):

You can just create a PHP project and then not create any PHP code. You will need the PHP plugin installed first.

Source: http://forums.netbeans.org/post-32661.html

Answer (score 5):

This isn't relevant to Netbeans 6.9, but [Netbeans 7.3](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/index.html) (in beta as of 11 January 2012) has support for strict HTML/JavaScript projects.

Answer (score 3):

If your still looking you could try this plugin:
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2006/08/netbeans_module.html